# Prove that $ \int _{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Prove 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Start with the fact that the integral of $D_{N}(\theta)$ equals $2\pi$, and note that the difference $$\frac{1}{\sin(\theta/2)}-\frac{2}{\theta}$$ 
is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
$$D_{N}(x)=\sum_{-N}^{N}e^{inx}=\frac{\sin((N+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}$$
Now I can only think to apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to the function
 $$\frac{1}{\sin(\theta/2)}-\frac{2}{\theta}$$ 
To get :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{e^{-in\theta}}{\sin(\theta/2)}-\frac{2e^{-in\theta}}{\theta})d\theta\to0$$But I don't know the steps to prove this.

Comment: It appears you're trying to follow a specific argument for the integral here. In order for the rest of us to understand what you're doing, we need more context about that argument. For example, what is $D_N$?

Comment: you have a limit as $n \to \infty$ on the LHS and an $n$ on the RHS

Comment: On the last line, both integrals are badly non-convergent.

Comment: I changed it according to the form of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @jmerry - If I had to guess at a glance, it probably is tied to the Dirichlet kernel somehow or another

Comment: Yes. $D_{N}(x)$ is the Nth Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: The main point is that if in the expression of $D_N$ you can replace in the denominator $\sin$ by the variable itself, a change of variables in its integral from say $[0, \pi]$ which you know as noted to be $\pi$ gives you the required integral from $0$ to $(N+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ and then you just let $N$ go to $\infty$. The required replacement follows since the difference continuous means that integrated against $\sin((N+\frac{1}{2})\pi)$ it goes to zero with $N$ going to $\infty$ by Riemann lebesgue so you are done

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi D_N(t)\,dt=2\pi.$$
Use that
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin((N+1/2)t)\left(\frac1{\sin t/2}-\frac 2t\right)\,dt\to0$$
as $N\to\infty$ (Riemann-Lebesgue) to deduce that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\sin((N+1/2)t)}{t}\,dx=\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you. I did It again with My original path, and I find It's essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Laplace transform
$$
   F(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx.
$$
Your integral is $\lim_{s\downarrow 0}F(s)$. For $s > 0$,
$$
    F'(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx}\sin xdx \\
   = \Im \int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}e^{ix}dx \\
   = \Im \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x(s+i)}dx \\
   = \Im \frac{1}{s+i}=\Im\frac{s-i}{1+s^2} \\=-\frac{1}{1+s^2}
$$
Therefore $F(s)=-\tan^{-1}(s)+C$ for some constant $C$. Because $F(\infty)=0$, then $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$. So
$$
      \int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}(s).
$$
Letting $s\downarrow 0$ gives
$$
          \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$